# How to see result from mysql query in netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, sql, debugging, netbeans-8

When I run the netbeans debugger on my project I can't see the resulting tables from my SQL queries. How can I see those results in the same way as I see other variables?

Here is an example query:

```
<sql:query var="query" dataSource="myDB">
SELECT * FROM data
</sql:query>
<c:set var="queryInfo" value="${query.rows[0]}"/>
```

How can I see the queryInfo/query table using the debygger? When I try to show the result as a html table I don't get any error messages and I only get an empty table. As such I suspect the query return an empty table.

EDIT: To further clarify, my full query is:

```
SELECT * FROM weather_station
WHERE weather_station.belong_to = ? <sql:param value="${param.id}"/>
ORDER BY when_inspected DESC
```

There might be a problem with line 2 in the query, but I am not able to find the walue of param.id. It works in a different query on the same page.

EDIT2: Even though this particular problem is solved, I am still wondering how I easy can see the result from a query in netbeans. When I use JSP it does not show as a variable in the output window.

Comment: Generally any errors are output in the netbeans 'output' window, which will show the server log output. Not that there is a guarantee that there actually is an error, it might also just be the case that the query produces no results. When in doubt, first run the query outside of your application, say in MySQL workbench.

Comment: Edit the question if you have more relevant information, don't dump code in comments.

Answer (score 1):

```
try{  
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  

Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/<database_name>","root","root");  

Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();  

ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("<Your_Query>");  

while(rs.next())  
System.out.println(rs.get<DataType_of_first_column>(1)+"  "+rs.get<DataType_of_second_column>(2)+"  "+rs.get<DataType_of_third_column>(3));  

conn.close();
rs.close();
stmt.close();

}catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}
```

This is the entire code right from connecting to mysql and getting the result of your query.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try after the holidays.