# How to connect a derby database to an jsp project

Tags: database, jsp, netbeans, derby

I am trying to establish a connection from a derby database to a JSP project, using an Apache Tomcat Server.

I created the database and manually added some entries. It seems like i can´t get a Connection to the db:

[image]

The table is shown correctly, but it doesn´t generate any entries.

Driver, user and Password are correct.

I am not sure if the

```
<sql:query dataSource="${mydb}" var="result">
            SELECT * FROM KUNDEN;
</sql:query>
```

part is correct.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>This is my title</title>
        <sql:setDataSource url="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Shop" var="mydb" 
                           driver="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver" user="root" password="password"/>
        <sql:query dataSource="${mydb}" var="result">
            SELECT * FROM KUNDEN;
        </sql:query>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Testing Java: <% out.print("Welcome to Ninja Loot"); %>!</p>

        <table border="1" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <th>KID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Strasse</th>
                <th>PLZ</th>
                <th>Ort</th>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach items="${kundenList}" var='kunden'>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <c:out value="${kunden.id}"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <c:out value="${kunden.name}"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <c:out value="${kunden.strasse}"/>
                    </td>        
                    <td>
                        <c:out value="${kunden.plz}"/>
                    </td>    
                    <td>
                        <c:out value="${kunden.ort}"/>
                    </td>    
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is incorrect: 
`<c:forEach items="${kundenList}" var='kunden'>`

Your variable that you stored the SQL result to is called result:

```
 <sql:query dataSource="${mydb}" var="result">
```

This means you'll need to set the 'result set' that you're accessing to refer to the rows in the "result" variable like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${result.rows}" var='kunden'>
```

The var name for the row can still be 'kunden' and you can refer to it the same below in the code.

Comment: Is there any way to debug this? I´d like to have a look in the result variable. But adding a breakpoint doesn´t show me the properties stored in result.

Comment: Sounds very similar to this, might work for you as well (swap out the driver name for the one that works with Derby) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33627869/how-to-see-result-from-mysql-query-in-netbeans